# Term used to refer to a graph whose nodes correspond to another graph with the same basic structure.

Tags: graph-theory, fractals

I am not familiar with Graph Theory, just a little bit. So, I would like to know whether there is a particular name (so I could study further searching for the right material) for a graph with the following feature:

We have a graph $H$ defined by a set of vertices $V(H)$ and set of edges $E(H)$. But this graph has a particular property, and like a sort of fractal, if you zoom in in a node, you will find a that it is composed by sub-graph that looks like the big one. Something like this:

[image]

So, let's say, above, node B is zoomed in, but the same would happen if you zoom in at A, C and D (just didn't draw the remaining edges).

Is there any name of clue for my search?

Thanks!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3381803/spatial-network-whose-vertices-are-actually-graphs-when-viewed-at-the-proper-dis

Comment: You may be looking for graph homomorphisms. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_homomorphism